# Storing sensitive data across web pages .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am currently using `HttpContext.Session.SetString()` to store some data accross webpages. Is this method safe to store sensitive data such as page access limitation data and etc ? Or is there a much safer method that I can securely store this data?

Comment: Session saved on client as a Cookie, and it is not safe! you have to use token and LocalStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using .NET Identity core module is convenient and reliable. It allows you to encrypt passwords, assign roles to users, authorize each controller and IAction method depending on the role assigned to a particular role. You can find more details about this from [Microsoft: Introduction to Identity on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).